# Terminal fails to show the local snapshots on my computer

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, snapshot

I typed

```
sudo tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
```

in terminal and entered the password. However, nothing happened. I suppose terminal to return all local snapshots on my computer, but it only returns `xxxs-MacBook-Pro-3:~ xxx$`. Does that mean there is no local snapshots in my computer? I don't believe it. My mac has updated to High Sierra and my external hard drive fails to backup because Time Machine could not create a local snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

What type of filesystem is your root device?  If I'm not mistaken it has to be the new APFS (i.e. not HFS+) in order to support local snapshots.  Not all upgrades to High Sierra will convert the root filesystem to APFS.

However backups using Time Machine should still work.

What does `tmutil status` show?